# how to create Generic object, and allow T is null

Tags: c#, generics

sorry, my english is poor.
how to create MyGeneric object, and allow T is null? 
thanks very muck.

```
public class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public int result { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }

    public T data { get; set; }
}

//...how to create MyGeneric object, and allow T is null?
var myGeneric = new MyGeneric<null> { 
    result = 1, 
    message = "" 
};

Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.result);
```

Comment: `null` is not a type. Why do you need this? What are you trying to do? do you want the value of `data` to be null?

Comment: yes, I want the value of date to be null.

Comment: can you use a `MyGeneric<string>`?. The default value of `string` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, generics vary based on types, not values.  This is because generics were intended to be used to allow the designing developer to create types that support members, parameters, and/or return values that vary based on what types a client developer wants to use the generic with.

For example, the built-in List<> type allows developers to store lists of whatever they want and List<> supports this as if the collection was a type-safe collection made just for that type.